# Advent of Code 2021 Day 19

Tags: programming-challenge, graph, kotlin

I am taking advantage of the recent layoffs to teach myself Kotlin. I am a career Java programmer, I've touched Kotlin before but not actively, and not for a few years. I wrote it all in one file mostly because I don't expect much to be reuseable, not looking for feedback on that too much. I am interested in feedback whether this is good canonical Kotlin, if there are things about the language I could do better.

[Advent of Code Day 19](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/19)

Some notes: `ScanIterator` (not included), does what it seems like it does, just turns a file into an iterator of `String` by line. And it's in Java anyway.

The approach to solve the problem is:

1. Compute the distances between all the nodes seen by each scanner
2. Look for equivalent matching distances in the other nodes. Since each node is guaranteed to have 12 matching nodes, look for the groups that have at least 11 matching distances.
3. Once those pairs of matching nodes are identified, use this information to compute what a transform would be from one coordinate system into another (`TransformRule`).
4. Then, fill out the graph to let every coordinate system be transformable into every other coordinate system (needed for part 2, not part 1)
5. For part 1, put every point into coordinate system for scanner 0 and use `Set` to remove duplicates, then count.
6. For part 2, find the transform rule that corresponds to the largest [Manhattan Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Here is my code!

```
package org.durron597.twentyone

import org.durron597.util.ScanIterator
import java.util.Scanner
import java.util.SortedMap
import kotlin.Comparator
import kotlin.math.abs

data class TransformRule(val offset: Int, val sign: Int, val source: Int, val target: Int)

fun main() {
    val iter = ScanIterator(Scanner(DayOne::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/2021/day19_input.txt")!!))

    val idToPoints = buildPointList(iter)

    val distances = idToPoints.mapValues { (_, v) -> toDistances(v) }
    val byDistance = pointPairsByDistance(distances)
    val elevenses = pairsWithElevenMatches(byDistance)
    val groupByScannerPairs = groupMatchesByScannerPairs(idToPoints, elevenses)
    val asInstructions = groupByScannerPairs.flatMap(::toInstructions).toMap()
    val fullInstructions = addAllMissingTransforms(asInstructions)
    val mergePoints = doMerge(idToPoints, fullInstructions)

    println("Part 1 answer: " + mergePoints.size)
    println("Part 2 answer: " + fullInstructions
            .mapValues { (_, v) -> v.fold(0) { acc, r -> acc + abs(r.offset) } }
            .maxBy { (_, v) -> v })
}

private fun buildPointList(iter: ScanIterator): Map<Int, List<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>> {
    var currentId = -1
    val idToPoints = mutableMapOf<Int, List<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>()

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val nextStr = iter.next()

        if ("" == nextStr) {
            currentId = -1
            continue
        }
        if (nextStr[1] == '-') {
            currentId = nextStr.filter(Char::isDigit).toInt()
            continue
        }
        val points = stringToTriple(nextStr)
        idToPoints.merge(currentId, listOf(points)) { v1, v2 -> v1 + v2 }
    }
    return idToPoints.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.toList() }.toMap()
}

private fun stringToTriple(nextStr: String) = nextStr.split(",")
        .map(String::toInt)
        .windowed(3, 3)
        .map { Triple(it[0], it[1], it[2]) }
        .first()

private fun toDistances(pointList: List<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>): Map<Int, List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>> {
    return pointList.flatMap { p -> pointList.map { p2 -> Pair(p, p2) } }
            .filter { pair -> compareTo(pair.first, pair.second) < 0 }
            .map { (t1, t2) ->
                Triple((t2.first - t1.first) * (t2.first - t1.first) +
                        (t2.second - t1.second) * (t2.second - t1.second) +
                        (t2.third - t1.third) * (t2.third - t1.third), t1, t2)
            }
            .groupBy { (d, _, _) -> d }
}

private fun compareTo(first: Triple<Int, Int, Int>, second: Triple<Int, Int, Int>): Int {
    return Comparator.comparing { t: Triple<Int, Int, Int> -> t.first }
            .thenComparing { t: Triple<Int, Int, Int> -> t.second }
            .thenComparing { t: Triple<Int, Int, Int> -> t.third }
            .compare(first, second)
}

private fun pointPairsByDistance(distances: Map<Int, Map<Int, List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>>>):
        SortedMap<Int, List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>> =
        distances.entries.fold(mutableMapOf<Int, List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>>()
        ) { acc, e ->
            val allToMerge = e.value.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.map { (_, k2, k3) -> Triple(e.key, k2, k3) } }
            allToMerge.forEach { (k, v) -> acc.merge(k, v) { v1, v2 -> v1 + v2 } }
            acc
        }.toSortedMap()

private fun pairsWithElevenMatches(byDistance: SortedMap<Int, List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>>) =
        byDistance.mapValues { (_, v) -> findCandidatePairs(v) }
                .values
                .flatten()
                .groupBy { p -> p }
                .mapValues { (_, v) -> v.size }
                .filterValues { i -> i > 10 }

private fun findCandidatePairs(distanceList: List<Triple<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>):
        List<Pair<Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>, Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>> {
    val uncrossed = distanceList.flatMap { (i, t1, t2) -> listOf(Pair(i, t1), Pair(i, t2)) }
    return uncrossed.flatMap { (s, t) -> uncrossed.map { (s2, t2) -> Pair(Pair(s, t), Pair(s2, t2)) } }
            .filter { (p1, p2) -> p1.first < p2.first }
}

private fun groupMatchesByScannerPairs(idToPoints: Map<Int, List<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>, elevenses: Map<Pair<Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>, Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>, Int>) =
        idToPoints.keys.toList()
                .flatMap { i -> idToPoints.keys.toList().map { j -> Pair(i, j) } }
                .filter { (i, j) -> i < j }
                .associate { (i, j) -> Pair(i, j) to elevenses.keys.filter { (p, p2) -> p.first == i && p2.first == j } }
                .filter { (_, v) -> v.size > 1 }

private fun toInstructions(entry: Map.Entry<Pair<Int, Int>, List<Pair<Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>, Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>>>):
        List<Pair<Pair<Int, Int>, List<TransformRule>>> {
    val lToRinstList = mutableListOf<TransformRule>()
    val rToLinstList = mutableListOf<TransformRule>()

    val firstPair = entry.value[0]
    val secondPair = entry.value[1]

    for (firstIndex in 0..2) {
        for (secondIndex in 0..2) {
            for (sign in -1..1 step 2) {
                val firstComparison = getComparison(firstPair, firstIndex, sign, secondIndex)
                val secondComparison = getComparison(secondPair, firstIndex, sign, secondIndex)

                if (firstComparison == secondComparison) {
                    lToRinstList.add(TransformRule(-firstComparison * -sign, -sign, firstIndex, secondIndex))
                    rToLinstList.add(TransformRule(firstComparison, -sign, secondIndex, firstIndex))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Cannot trust the results, try to handle this more gracefully only if it breaks (which it didn't)
    if (lToRinstList.size > 3) {
        return emptyList()
    }

    return listOf(Pair(entry.key, lToRinstList.toList()), Pair(Pair(entry.key.second, entry.key.first), rToLinstList.toList()))
}

private fun getComparison(firstPair: Pair<Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>, Pair<Int, Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>, firstIndex: Int, sign: Int, secondIndex: Int) =
        firstPair.first.second.toList()[firstIndex] + sign * firstPair.second.second.toList()[secondIndex]

private fun addAllMissingTransforms(asInstructions: Map<Pair<Int, Int>, List<TransformRule>>): Map<Pair<Int, Int>, List<TransformRule>> {
    val maxId = asInstructions.keys.flatMap { p -> p.toList() }.toSet().max()

    val result = asInstructions.toMutableMap()

    while (result.keys.size < ((maxId + 1) * (maxId + 2)) / 2) {
        for (i in 0..maxId) {
            for (j in 0..maxId) {
                if (result.containsKey(Pair(i, j))) continue

                val neededTransforms = identifyAddableNeededTransforms(result, i)
                neededTransforms.forEach { (s, m, t) ->
                    result[Pair(s, t)] = mergeTransform(result[Pair(s, m)]!!, result[Pair(m, t)]!!)
                }
                neededTransforms.forEach { (s, m, t) ->
                    result[Pair(t, s)] = mergeTransform(result[Pair(t, m)]!!, result[Pair(m, s)]!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toMap()
}

private fun identifyAddableNeededTransforms(result: MutableMap<Pair<Int, Int>, List<TransformRule>>, i: Int) =
        result.keys.filter { (s, _) -> s == i }
                .flatMap { (_, t) ->
                    result.keys.filter { (s, _) -> s == t }
                            .map { (s2, t2) -> Triple(i, s2, t2) }
                }
                .filter { (s, _, t2) -> s != t2 }
                .filter { (s, _, t) -> !result.containsKey(Pair(s, t)) }

private fun mergeTransform(first: List<TransformRule>, second: List<TransformRule>): List<TransformRule> {
    val result = mutableListOf<TransformRule>()

    for (i in 0..2) {
        val firstRule = first.find { t -> t.target == i }!!
        val secondRule = second.find { t -> t.source == i }!!
        result.add(TransformRule((firstRule.offset * secondRule.sign) + secondRule.offset,
                firstRule.sign * secondRule.sign, firstRule.source, secondRule.target))
    }

    return result.toList()
}

private fun doMerge(idToPoints: Map<Int, List<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>, asInstructions: Map<Pair<Int, Int>, List<TransformRule>>):
        Set<Triple<Int, Int, Int>> {
    val map = idToPoints.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.toSet() }

    val targetMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Set<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>>()
    for ((k, v) in map.entries) {
        if (k == 0) {
            targetMap.merge(k, v) { v1, v2 -> v1 + v2 }
        } else {
            val transformed = doTransform(v, asInstructions[Pair(k, 0)]!!)
            targetMap.merge(0, transformed) { v1, v2 -> v1 + v2 }
        }
    }

    return targetMap[0]!!
}

private fun doTransform(v: Set<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>, trs: List<TransformRule>): Set<Triple<Int, Int, Int>> {
    return v.map { t ->
        Triple(applyTransform(t, trs.find { r -> r.target == 0 }!!),
                applyTransform(t, trs.find { r -> r.target == 1 }!!),
                applyTransform(t, trs.find { r -> r.target == 2 }!!))
    }
            .toSet()
}

private fun applyTransform(t: Triple<Int, Int, Int>, r: TransformRule): Int {
    return r.offset + t.toList()[r.source] * r.sign
}
```

Comment: Friendly suggestion: Code long like this could really use all the resources including the missing java class and the .txt file. Then reviewers can execute and try on their own. Even better if there were a few unit tests. I was contemplating doing review a few times, but this was a bit discouraging.